# Type error: Cannot call method "getDataRange" of null

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to publish this code, but everytime when I run this code I get an error

> Cannot call method"getDataRange" of null.

Here is my code

```
function 
        
    doGet() {  
 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheet id');
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('sheet name');
    var data = sheet.getDataRange();
 
    var dateFilter= Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(0).build(); 
    var ageFilter = Charts.newNumberRangeFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(7).build();
    var transportFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(2).build();
    var nameFilter = Charts.newStringFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(1).build();
   
    var tableChart = Charts.newTableChart().setDimensions(700, 300)
                     .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]))
                    .build();
  
    var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
                  .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition()
                  .setColumns([1,7])).build();
 
    var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(data)
                 .bind([dateFilter,ageFilter, transportFilter, nameFilter], [tableChart,    pieChart])
                 .build();
 
    var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(50);
 
    var todaysdate = new Date();
    app.add(app.createLabel(todaysdate));
    app.add(app.createHTML('<h1 style="text-align:center;">DEMO</h1>'));
 
    var filterPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
    var chartPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  
 
    filterPanel.add(dateFilter).add(ageFilter).add(transportFilter).add(nameFilter).setSpacing(10);
    chartPanel.add(tableChart).add(pieChart).setSpacing(50);
 
    dashboard.add(app.createVerticalPanel().add(filterPanel).add(chartPanel));
    app.add(dashboard);
 
    var service = ScriptApp.getService();
    service.enable(service.Restriction.ALL);
   
    return app;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error indicate `sheet` is null. Make sure you are using the correct sheet name in `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('sheet name');`. Copy and paste the sheet name from the google doc if there are invisible characters.

Comment: Hi,i Copy pasted the sheet name. I still get the same error.

Comment: @sunilvalluri, are you hitting the `Run` button or `Deploy as web app`? Note the latter option require you to launch a new version (in File -> Manage version)

Comment: ,Appreciate your patience. im launching with the new version only.Not able to figure out where the error is coming from.

Comment: to clarify, 'sheet name' does not refer to the name of the google spreadsheet but to the name of the tab at the bottom of the worksheet. Sheet !== SpreadSheet. In case anyone else can avoid my pain....